Selecting subsets $G$ of a set $\mathcal{K}$ of integers so that atleast one subset of $G$ has consecutive integers in wrap around sense.
Let $\mathcal{K}=[1,2,\cdots,K]$ be a set of cardinality $K$. For parameters $a$ and $p$, taking integer values, how many subsets $G$ of $\mathcal{K}$ exist of cardinality $(1+a+p)$ such that there is atleast one subset of $G$ that is of cardinality $a$ and have consecutive elements. Elements are consecutive in a wrap around fashion, that is, $K$ is consecutive to $1$. For example, $G=\{1,3,5,7\}$ has 1 subset of cardinality $2$ for $K=7$ that has consecutive integers, $\{7,1\}$.
My approach:
I select $K$ subsets of $\mathcal{K}$ of cardinality $a$ with consecutive elements, that is $\{1,2,\cdots,a\}, \{2,3,\cdots,a+1\}$, and so on. For each of these sets, there are a remaining of $K-a$ elements of $\mathcal{K}$ from which I select all possible subsets of cardinality $(p+1)$. Finally I use inclusion-exclusion. However, this is proving to be very complicated.

Have you solved the version without wrap around? I have a memory of doing something at least very similar (there are like these blocks of length $a$ and you see how they can cluster on top of each other) and got a little better formula than a brute force calculation (like, you iterate over integer partitions of $K$ instead of all subsets of $[K]$. But that circular wrap around seems to give give problems: if you make a collection of block clusters, where does it start? And there are then those pesky rotational symmetries...
